# Paypal Standard - time limit

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, standards

I am sending customers to Paypal using Paypal Standard and a classic html form. 
I need to ensure that customers pay within 10 minutes. 
I was hoping to fund a variable that wold allow me to set a datetime beyond which the transaction could not be accepted any more by Paypal.
I went through the variables at
https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables
I did not find anything

Does anybody know how to set such a time limit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is not a variable within the PayPal button variables that allows you to set a time limit on how long the buyer has to pay.  The only thing that may be close to working for you, and this would also depend on how many buttons you will be creating and having at one time would created hosted buttons on the fly when they are ready to pay.  You could use the [BMCreateButton API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/bmcreatebutton-api-operation-nvp) to create the button.  Then have your system generate the code on your website so that the buyer can click the button.  When the button is created, store it in a database along with a time stamp.  Then set your set up to run a cron job every so often, checking the time stamp.  If the time stamp is outside of the period of time that you are wanting the buyer to be able to click the button, have your system use the [BMManageButtonStatus API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/bmmanagebuttonstatus-api-operation-nvp) to delete the button from your account.  This will then prevent the buyer from clicking on it and making a payment with the button.